# Delphi SOAP strange tag

Tags: xml, delphi, soap

I have this interface in Delphi XE SOAP server project:

```
type TRequest=class(tremotable)
...
type tCollection=class(tremotable)
...

imyintf = interface(IInvokable)
        ['{929F54BA-50C1-47A7-91F8-3EC61931F80E}']
        function GetSomething(const params:TRequest)
                  : tCollection; stdcall;
      end;
```

All fields have index IS_REF=$0080. Initialisation looks like this:

```
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(imyintf),'ns');
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(imyintf), ioDocument);
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(imyintf), ioLiteral);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(TRequest,'Request','Request');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(tCollection,'Collection','Collection');
```

Generated by SOAPUI request looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="ns" xmlns:ns2="http://www.regionh.dk/regionh.dk/cis/xml.schema/" xmlns:urn="urn:Intf-icis2opus" xmlns="http://www.regionh.dk/regionh.dk/xml.schema/" xmlns:ns3="http://rep.oio.dk/cpr.dk/xml/schemas/core/2005/03/18/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:Request soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <params xsi:type="get:Request" xmlns:get="Request" xmlns="">
...
         </params>
      </ns:Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But client wants to send XML request without  tag. Params is a name of input parameter in my function. If I send like he wants, I have nil in request object. What shall I change to make my application work without that tag?

=============================

Resolved. I put all fields from request "param" an input parameter to the function. Like this:

```
function GetSomething(const ...<there are variables from "Trequest" object>...)
              : TCollection;
```